# No Material widget found with Hero & Ink.image widget

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design

I am using `Ink.image` widget because I want to splash/ripple effect on image but if I use it with `Hero` widget its gives error that `Material` widget ancestors not found which is not true because `Scaffold` is a `Material` widget but I also try to explicitly add `Material` widget below `InkWell` widget but nothing happens it's still not detecting it.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        splashColor: Colors.amber.withAlpha(150),
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      home: const Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Home"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const Detail(),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            child: Hero(
              tag: "tag",
              child: Ink.image(
                image: const NetworkImage(
                  "https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/0dbfcc7a59cd1cf16282.png",
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Detail extends StatelessWidget {
  const Detail({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Detail"),
      ),
      body: Hero(
        tag: "tag",
        child: Ink.image(
          image: const NetworkImage(
            "https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/0dbfcc7a59cd1cf16282.png",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### I want this behaviour but without errors

[image]

```
Restarted application in 2,605ms.
I/flutter (13108): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (13108): The following assertion was thrown building Ink(bg: BoxDecoration(image:
I/flutter (13108): DecorationImage(NetworkImage("https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/0dbfcc7a59cd1cf16282.png",
I/flutter (13108): scale: 1.0), Alignment.center, scale 1.0, opacity 1.0, FilterQuality.low)), dirty, state:
I/flutter (13108): _InkState#82f44):
I/flutter (13108): No Material widget found.
I/flutter (13108): Ink widgets require a Material widget ancestor.
I/flutter (13108): In Material Design, most widgets are conceptually "printed" on a sheet of material. In Flutter's
I/flutter (13108): material library, that material is represented by the Material widget. It is the Material widget
I/flutter (13108): that renders ink splashes, for instance. Because of this, many material library widgets require that
I/flutter (13108): there be a Material widget in the tree above them.
I/flutter (13108): To introduce a Material widget, you can either directly include one, or use a widget that contains
I/flutter (13108): Material itself, such as a Card, Dialog, Drawer, or Scaffold.
I/flutter (13108): The specific widget that could not find a Material ancestor was:
I/flutter (13108):   Ink
I/flutter (13108): The ancestors of this widget were:
I/flutter (13108):   ...
I/flutter (13108):   MediaQuery
I/flutter (13108):   AnimatedBuilder
I/flutter (13108):   FadeTransition
I/flutter (13108):   IgnorePointer
I/flutter (13108):   Positioned
I/flutter (13108):   ...
I/flutter (13108):
I/flutter (13108): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (13108):   Ink Ink:file:///C:/Users/Burhan/Desktop/test/lib/main.dart:67:22
I/flutter (13108):
I/flutter (13108): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (13108): #0      debugCheckHasMaterial.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:29:7)
I/flutter (13108): #1      debugCheckHasMaterial (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:50:4)
I/flutter (13108): #2      _InkState.build (package:flutter/src/material/ink_decoration.dart:300:12)
I/flutter (13108): #3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4992:27)
I/flutter (13108): #4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4878:15)
I/flutter (13108): #5      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11)
I/flutter (13108): #6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
I/flutter (13108): #7      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4859:5)
I/flutter (13108): #8      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5041:11)
I/flutter (13108): #9      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4853:5)
I/flutter (13108): ...     Normal element mounting (57 frames)
I/flutter (13108): #66     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
I/flutter (13108): #67     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6435:36)
I/flutter (13108): #68     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
I/flutter (13108): #69     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5964:32)
I/flutter (13108): #70     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6460:17)
I/flutter (13108): #71     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3570:15)
I/flutter (13108): #72     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
I/flutter (13108): #73     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11)
I/flutter (13108): #74     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
I/flutter (13108): #75     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2667:19)
I/flutter (13108): #76     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
I/flutter (13108): #77     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:378:5)
I/flutter (13108): #78     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1175:15)
I/flutter (13108): #79     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1104:9)
I/flutter (13108): #80     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1015:5)
I/flutter (13108): #81     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:148:13)
I/flutter (13108): #82     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:318:5)
I/flutter (13108): #83     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
I/flutter (13108):
I/flutter (13108): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69323013/13997210) answer

Comment: this link u refer is not related to my question its about image snot showing up in but i have an issue with the material widget not found by ink.image

Comment: check my [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74096532/13997210) answer I think your problem is resolved

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil your answer is same as @Denzel answer which make `Ink.image` point less

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After so much try and fail i finally go to flutter github repo and create issue there but they also just closed the issue with same code as @Denzel answer so i have to dig all issues and i found there is issue from 2019 which discussing the bug in flutter sdk which is still not fixed as i am using latest 3.3 stable version you can see further about that issue at this [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28326) but the the solution is that just wrap the whole application with `Material` which is wired i know but that works.

```dart
runApp(
    Material(
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
```

You can try below code to verify this bug

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      const Material(
        child: App(),
      ),
    );

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        splashColor: Colors.amber.withAlpha(150),
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      home: const Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Home"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const Detail(),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            child: Hero(
              tag: "tag",
              child: Ink.image(
                image: const NetworkImage(
                  "https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/0dbfcc7a59cd1cf16282.png",
                ),
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const Detail(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Detail extends StatelessWidget {
  const Detail({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Detail"),
      ),
      body: Hero(
        tag: "tag",
        child: Ink.image(
          image: const NetworkImage(
            "https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/0dbfcc7a59cd1cf16282.png",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Wrap it with Material as it must have a Material widget as an ancestor. The Material widget is where the ink reactions are actually painted. This matches the material design premise wherein the Material is what is actually reacting to touches by spreading ink.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {     
return Hero(       
child: Material(child: Ink.image())}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() => runApp(const App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Home"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const Detail(),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 100,
            child: Hero(
              tag: "tag",
              child: Material(
                child: Ink.image(
                  height: 100,
                  image: Image.network(
                    "https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/0dbfcc7a59cd1cf16282.png",
                  ).image,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Detail extends StatelessWidget {
  const Detail({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Detail"),
      ),
      body: Hero(
        tag: "tag",
        child: Material(
          child: Ink.image(
              image: Image.network(
            "https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/0dbfcc7a59cd1cf16282.png",
          ).image),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60665227/11623001), what I observe is that a widget wrapped with the `Hero` widget is not necessarily wrapped with a `Material` widget, so you have to rewrap the child widget of a Hero widget with a `Material` widget again.

Comment: Well, it works erros are gone but now this makes the whole Ink.image widget is useless because i have used it to show ripple on the image not behind the image but wrapping with material makes it ripple show behind

Comment: You can refer to the documentation 
here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Ink-class.html

Comment: i have already seen this but its simple example of ink.image without hero

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand what you need.

Comment: simples splash/ripple effect on above image but with hero animation also i have updated my code to show what i exactly want but without error

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Stack( 
      children: [
        Positioned.fill(
          child: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
            child: Image.network(
              "https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage- bucket/0dbfcc7a59cd1cf16282.png"),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned.fill(
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: InkWell(onTap: () {}),
        ),
      ),
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, just wrap your `Ink.image()` with material widget

your `Home` widget:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Home"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const Detail(),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 100,
            child: Hero(
              tag: "tag",
              child: Material(
                child: Ink.image(
                  height: 100,
                  image: Image.network(
                    "https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/0dbfcc7a59cd1cf16282.png",
                  ).image,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Your `Detail` widget:

```
class Detail extends StatelessWidget {
  const Detail({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Detail"),
      ),
      body: Hero(
        tag: "tag",
        child: Material(
          child: Ink.image(
              image: Image.network(
            "https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/0dbfcc7a59cd1cf16282.png",
          ).image),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```